# Errors on a python word game

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and It always says I have a bad input on lines 2,4, and 10 and when I put a < in front of the second line it approves it and when I put > for the 4th line it approves it and I tried it for the 10th line but it didn't work

```
start = int(input("type 1 to begin or 2 to buy items: "))
if start = 1 :
    print("welcome to this game")
if start = 2 :
    ranged = 0
    melee = 1
    fighting = 0
    money = 100
    shop = int(input("1 for sword or two for arrows: "))
        if shop = 1 :
            money = money-100
            fighting = fighting+1
            melee = melee+1
            start = int(input("type 1 to begin or 2 to buy items: "))
        if shop = 2 :
            money = money-100
            fighting = fighting+0.5
            ranged = ranged+1
            start = int(input("type 1 to begin or 2 to buy items: "))
        else:
        print("invalid selection")`
```

## Umm so I kind of changed it a little but it still has errors on line 12 where it says it cannot recognize x but I have already defined it earlier

```
start = int(input('type 1 to begin or 2 to buy items: '))
if start == 1 :
    print("welcome to this game")
    print("you will face off with a evil monster named york for the first adventure")
    print("I am york and I will eat you")
if start == 2 :
    x = float(input('type 1 or 2 to buy items: '))
    ranged = 0
    melee = 1
    fighting = 0
    money = 100
if x == 1:
    money = money-100
    print(money)
    fighting = fighting+1
    melee = melee+1
    start = int(input('type 1 to begin or 2 to buy items: '))
    if start == 1 :
        print("welcome to this game")
    else:
        print("visit the shop another time")
if x == 2 :
    money = money-100
    fighting = fighting+0.5
    ranged = ranged+1
    start = int(input("type 1 to begin or 2 to buy items: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

The "=" sign in Python is for assigning a value to a variable.
Example:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> x+1
4
```

For comparison use "==".
Example:

```
>>> if x == 3:
...     print "That is true"
...
That is true
>>> if x == 2:
...     print "that is true"
...
>>>
```